# Does wordpress create activity, update logs?

Tags: admin, updates, activation

Does wordpress create any dated logs of activity?
ie core updates, plugin download dates etc?

Comment: I use a plugin called [BTEV - Bluetrait Event Viewer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bluetrait-event-viewer/) that does this job quite well.

Comment: No you can't. But you can do the same using plugin, I am using [WP-Activity](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-activity/) Really grate.

Comment: A plugin called [Stream](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/) also solves this well.

Comment: I was looking at the same problem and i found this plugin. It was updated 2 weeks ago so it might be a good contemporary solution: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/ > Keep an audit log of all changes and under the hood WordPress activity to ensure productivity and thwart possible WordPress hacker attacks

Comment: Yes, WordPress plugin available to check log in activity. Check: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-activity-log/
This plugin helps to tack and monitor user's activity in wordpress based site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn’t. You could hook into the appropriate filters and save the information in an option or in a custom post type. I would log updates to PHP, MySQL and the server software too. Would be an interesting project. :)

Comment: ah shame - just needed to check some dates against some scripts errors that may be due to client running wp & plugin updates. Found a few plugins now and looking into them. Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Check against Apache/nginx/or-your-flavor access logs and compare the dates of `wp-admin/plugin.php` against whatever time frames you have + check dates of files/directories created. The `/updates/` directory should have something for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [enabled debug logging](https://www.wpsecurityauditlog.com/wordpress-admin/enabling-wordpress-debug/) then it will. You can do this by editing your `wp-config.php` file and adding the following line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

For more info see [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG), which was added to WordPress as of version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress alone cannot do it.

There are several options in terms of plugins that track the activities such as core/plugin/theme updates.

I am using [WP Admin Audit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-audit/) for having an event log on my sites.